# Cant see device with lastest adb.exe version but I can see it with an old adb version in Windows

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, usb-debugging

My device is a [Wolder Manhattan 7" Android](http://www.wolderelectronics.com/productos/80-mitab-manhattan#caract) tablet which is a clone copy of [BQ Pascal 2](http://www.bqreaders.com/productos/pascal-2.html).

In order to get root and use adb, most guides use the *BQ Pascal 2* Windows drivers for *Wolder Manhattan*:

http://www.htcmania.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=110451&d=1334723079

**My system:**
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.
- Latest version of the Android SDK installed (adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools).

**Driver setup:**
I have followed the guide to install the drivers and they have been installed perfectly in Windows.
The device is shown in Windows Hardware Devices Manager as: *"Android Phone - Android ADB Interface."*
*"USB Debugging"* and *"Mass Storage"* is enabled and Im already *"root"* in my device.

**Tests with adb versions:**

- Using adb.exe version  1.0.31 (from the latest SDK) (796kb) doesn't show any connected devices:

  ```
  ...\adt-bundle-windows-x8\sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe devices
  List of devices attached
  ```
- Using and old adb.exe version 1.0.29 from 2012 (158kb), which is in the BQ Pascal 2 drivers, the device is shown:

  ```
  ...\Root Pascal 2\RooT\files>adb.exe devices adb server is out of date. killing...
  daemon started successfully
  List of devices attached
  0123456789ABCDEF        device
  ```

**Question:**

Why does the old `adb.exe` version from 01/11/12 work and shows the device, and the lastest one from the Android sdk doesn't show anything?

I have also tested with other drivers but I get the same result, the device is only shown using the old `adb.exe`.

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the SDK and checking the md5 hash? Have you tried uninstalling the SDK and re-installing from a fresh download? Also, the 1.0.31 update is really only necessary if you need to interact with Android 4.2.2

Comment: Thank yo so much for the edit improve, a lot better now Izzy. I will check md5 hashes and more tests and report later.